# Unable to get text from textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my jquery script, for some reason the top two buttons are displaying undefined instead of doing what buttons underneath do.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I need the two buttons on the top working as the button underneath.

HTML:

```
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Typ</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Code HTML</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
<div class="form">
<textarea name="code_g1" id="code_g1" placeholder="" rows="5" cols="50">https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png</textarea>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $(".IMGtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).next().next('.form').find('textarea').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $(this).next().next('.form').find('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
$(function(){
  $(".FLASHtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).next('.form').find('textarea').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $(this).next('.form').find('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/hd4uao12/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - should be like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u6byatfk/

Comment: As per your html structure $(this).next().next('.form') will only work for bottom buttons. Use $('.form').find('textarea').val().

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use it, because I'm planning to have multiple forms like this on the website. If I will do $('.form').find('textarea').val() the same content will go to all textarea https://jsfiddle.net/cknytax0/1/ - I want the contect to go to the closest textarea to the button.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` (`type_g1`): this is invalid HTML. While that won't impact this question you are likely to have other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like that ?

```js
$(function(){
  $(".IMGtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).parents('.form-table').find('.form').find('textarea').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
$(function(){
  $(".FLASHtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).parents('.form-table').find('.form').find('textarea').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Typ</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Code HTML</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
<div class="form">
<textarea name="code_g1" id="code_g1" placeholder="" rows="5" cols="50">https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png</textarea>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work for me, because I need to have multiple forms like this on the website. The content will go to all textarea https://jsfiddle.net/wo4vujx0/1/

Comment: Sorry! its actually working! THANK YOU, I just have to change the $('textarea').val(display_html); to $(this).parents('.form-table').find('.form').find('textarea').val();

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler won't work for the top two buttons, since `$(this).next().next('.form')` will yield an empty jQuery object. Instead, I would replace finding the textarea with an id based selector: `$('#code_g1').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your path was incorrect.

**from:**
var url = $(this).next().next('.form').find('textarea').val();

**to:**
var url = $('#code_g1').val();

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
  $(".IMGtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $('#code_g1').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
$(function(){
  $(".FLASHtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $('#code_g1').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});

});
```

```css
textarea {
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Typ</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Code HTML</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
<div class="form">
<textarea name="code_g1" id="code_g1" placeholder="" rows="5" cols="50">https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png</textarea>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your html structure $(this).next().next('.form') will only work for bottom buttons. Use $('.form').find('textarea').val()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are trying to do is this:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".IMGtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $('textarea').val();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $('textarea').text(display_html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Typ</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Code HTML</th>
<td>
<button class="IMGtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">JPEG/PNG/GIF</button>
<button class="FLASHtoHTML" id="type_g1" name="type_g1" type="button">Flash</button>
<div class="form">
<textarea name="code_g1" id="code_g1" placeholder="" rows="5" cols="50">https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png</textarea>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the "val()" to ".text()"

```
    $(function(){
  $(".IMGtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).next().next('.form').find('textarea').text();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $(this).next().next('.form').find('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
$(function(){
  $(".FLASHtoHTML").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).next('.form').find('textarea').text();
    var display_html = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    $(this).next('.form').find('textarea').val(display_html);
  });
});
```

Thanks